# objective c remove copy button from menu bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, copy, selector, menuitem

I'm writing an application that uses webkit to read epubs. When I'm selecting text by long press , the menu bar opens, and there should only be Facebook, and Twitter buttons. So here is my code how do I did it :

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
if (action == @selector(facebookItemClicked:) || action == @selector(twitterItemClicked:)) {
return YES;
}else if (action == @selector(copy:)){
NSLog(@"copy");
} return NO;}
```

Here is how I initialize menu Items

`UIMenuItem *facebookMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" action:@selector(facebookItemClicked:)];
UIMenuItem *twitterMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" action:@selector(twitterItemClicked:)];`

But the problem is that copy selector never appears it as action so I cannot catch it and every time menu bar is shown there is also a copy button beside Facebook and Twitter.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to rework your wording.  Parts are unintelligible.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really got your comment.

Comment: "never appears it as action so I cannot catch it" is very hard to understand.

Comment: I mean when canPerformAction "runs" trough all actions it can perform such as copy, paste, cut , define, Facebook, twitter etc. in this row of actions copy action doesn't appear so I can remove it, but it should be there. I cannot understand what is the reason that copy action is not in that list?

Comment: Question should be tagged iOS. The `UIResponder` docs state "Note that if your class returns NO for a command, another responder further up the responder chain may still return YES, enabling the command." so it may not be possible to eliminate `copy:` anyway. Or, maybe your `UIApplication` or something at the window level is returning `YES`, and you'll need to override that to stop it.

Comment: hmmm I think webkit somewhere returns yes. But I can't understand where. So thanks for a direction...

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem.

Default UIWebView was overriding my menuBar actions. So I created a class `CustomWebView` inherited from UIWebView added

```
+ (void)initialize{
UIMenuItem *itemA = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A" action:@selector(a:)];
UIMenuItem *itemB = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B" action:@selector(b:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemA, itemB, nil]];
//    [itemA release];
//    [itemB release];
 }

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
BOOL can = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
if (action == @selector(a:) || action == @selector(b:))
    {
        can = YES;
    }
if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        can = NO;
    }
NSLog(@"%@ perform action %@ with sender %@.", can ? @"can" : @"cannot", NSStringFromSelector(action), sender);
return can;
}
```

which overrides menubar actions in `webview` and then I use this `CustomWebView` in other classes that use webvew.